# $\frac{(x^2+1)\cot x}{3- \cos x \csc x }$ how to differentiate it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

> If $f(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)\cot x}{3- \cos x \csc x }$ so, find $f′$.

I tried to solve the problem in two ways.

1.

$$f(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)\cot x}{3- \cos x \csc x }$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{x^2\cot x+\cot x}{3- \cos x \csc x }$$

So,

$$f'(x)=\frac{(-2x \csc^2 (x)- \csc (x))(3 - \cos (x) \csc (x))-(\sin (x) \cot (x) \csc (x))(x^2\cot (x) + \cot (x))}{[3- \cos (x) \csc (x)]^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{-6x \csc^2 (x) - 3 \csc^2 (x) + 2x \cos (x) \csc^3 (x) +\cos (x) \csc^3 (x) -x^2\sin (x) \cot^2 (x) \csc (x) - \sin (x) \cot^2 (x) \csc (x)}{ [3 - \cos (x) \csc (x)]^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{-csc (x)[6x\csc (x) +3\csc (x) - 2x  \cos (x)\csc^2(x)-\cos (x) \csc^2 (x)+x^2\sin (x)\cot^2 (x)+\sin (x) \cot^2 (x)]}{[3-\cos (x) \csc (x)]^2}$$

2.
$$f(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)\cot x}{3- \cos x \csc x }$$
Let $$u=(x^2+1)\cot (x)$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=2x \cot (x) - x^2\csc^2 (x) - \csc^2 (x)$$

Then,

$$f'(x)=\frac{(2x\cot (x)-x^2 \csc^2 (x)-\csc^2 (x))(3-\cos (x)\csc (x))-(\sin (x) \cot (x) \csc (x))(x^2+1)\cot (x)}{[3-\cos (x) \csc (x)]^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{6x\cot (x) -3x^2\csc^2 (x)-3 \csc^2 (x)-2x\cos (x) \cot (x) \csc (x)+x^2 \csc^3 (x)+\cos (x) \csc^3 (x)-x^2 \sin (x) \cot^2 (x) \csc (x)-\sin (x) \cot^2 (x)\csc (x)}{[3-\cos (x) \csc (x)]^2}$$

Both answer are different. Actually, which answer is correct? I am not sure if I did any mistake while typing cause, that's too big.

Comment: In the first way, the derivative of $(x^2 + 1) \cot(x)$ on the numerator looks a bit off

Comment: @Buraian I added how I differentiate it... I am not sure if I did any mistake

Comment: First expand the fraction by $\sin(x)$ to get $$(x^2+1)\frac{\cos(x)}{3\sin(x)-\cos(x)}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding mistakes in both your methods. For the first one, $x^2\cot x +\cot x$ has derivative $ -\csc^2 x(x^2+1)+2x\cot x$, which is not what you wrote. For the second one, you made a mistake in the derivative of $\csc x \cos x$. It's better of you simply write $\csc x \cos x=\cot x$ and then differentiate. Also note that the product rule is :$$(fg)'=g f'+f g'$$ and NOT $(fg)'=f'g'$.